# Which Jenkins special URLs are there?

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins has a number of special URLs... the ones for controlling jobs are lightly documented, but while many of the "special ones" appear in various articles, I have never seen them documented in one place.

The ones I know of are:

```
http://jenkins:8080/restart
http://jenkins:8080/safeRestart
http://jenkins:8080/quietDown
http://jenkins:8080/cancelQuietDown
```

Failing that, what other special Jenkins URLs to you know about and use?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a great reference for these, but [Jenkins APIs](https://android-build.linaro.org/jenkins/api/) has many of them.  Search for links that say "this URL".

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Said link is dead.

Comment: I was searching for this recently too, the link that is broke is the "REST API" link at the bottom of the Jenkins server page, which points to [your jenkins server]/api/